# Chrome Tabs.CaptureVisibleTab is Undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a pop-up that will display the visible tab as a small image. The *ImgSrc* returned from the chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() function is "Undefined". I have tried running this from various places. I can verify that the tab returned from the tabs.Query() is not-null, so the tabs[0].id is not null.

Am I doing this incorrectly?

Here's my manifest, popup.html and popup.js files:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "SuperFave",
  "description": "Saves favorites demo",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "<all_urls>"
  ]
}
```

popup.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  chrome.tabs.query( {
      // gets the window the user can currently see
      active: true, 
      currentWindow: true 
    },
    function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab( 
        tabs[0].id,
        function (src) {
          // displays a link to the image. Can be replaced by an alert() to 
          // verify the result is 'undefined'
          $('body').append("<a href='" + src + "'>" + tabs[0].url + "</a>");
        }
      ); 
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

captureVisibleTab works only on the current active tab in a window. Thus I needed to pass in the window-id, not the tab-id.

popup.js needed to be:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  chrome.tabs.query( {
      // gets the window the user can currently see
      active: true, 
      currentWindow: true 
    },
    function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab( 
        chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT,
        function (src) {
          // displays a link to the image. Can be replaced by an alert() to 
          // verify the result is 'undefined'
          $('body').append("<a href='" + src + "'>" + tabs[0].url + "</a>");
        }
      ); 
    }
  );
});
```